# cant assign value in subscribe block using reactiveCocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to set value after mapping data using Reactive Cocoa. Here is my code:

```
- (RACSignal *)getNews{

    RACSignal *sign = [self.manager rac_GET:MAIN_URL_NEWS parameters:self.parameters];

    return sign;
}
```

Then i do:

```
@weakify(self);
    [[[self getNews] map:^id(NSDictionary *response) {

    // Mapping
        NSArray * array = [response valueForKey:@"data"];
        NSMutableArray *localArray = [NSMutableArray new];


        [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            NewsParseer *news = [[NewsParseer alloc]init];
            [news mts_setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:[[response valueForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:idx]];
            NSLog(@"Object memory %@", news);
            NSLog(@"Newnew %@", news.title);
            [localArray addObject:news];

        }];

        return localArray;


    }] subscribeNext:^(NSArray* x) {
        NSLog(@"Data is %@", x);

    }];

    NSLog(@"data array %@", self.dataArray);
```

@"Data is %@" is output correct value, therefore, in subscribeNext we got correct value.
But, @"data array" output is

```
data array (
)
```

Why is that happening?

Of course i did initialize array:

```
self.dataArray   = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Even provide getter method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)dataArray{

    if(!_dataArray){
        _dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return _dataArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're ever setting `self.dataArray` to equal to result of `x` in your subscribeNext block.

Try:

`self.dataArray = x;` after your log statement in subscribeNext.

Also, the signal is asynchronous - it's highly unlikely that your logging of `self.dataArray` will occur *after* your signal completes. It will probably happen prior to the completion of the signals work.

Comment: i solve this problem with simply removing @strongify(self), however, without idea what problem it was, You was right with assumption that main thread NSLog will complete first (before subscribe next).